# transition ease-in-out; is not working

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am trying to use simple transiton, but I don't understand why it is not working. Could you help me? I put `transition: ease-in-out;` in container...

my code:

```
.container{
    width:250px;
    height:300px;
    background:#00f;
    position:relative;
    transition: ease-in-out;
}

.show{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    color:#000;
    text-indent:5px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

.container:hover > .show{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mAzsL/44/

I use this as example: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Ne9/53/

UPDATE: 
My aim was to get effect which is called 'fade in a box' - I wasn't precise, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

On new requirements, the transition effect needs to be different, please refer the below snippet.

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #00f;
  position: relative;
}

.show {
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0;
  height:30%;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0px;
  right:0px;
  color: #000;
  text-indent: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover>.show {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="show">Lorem </div>
</div>
```

**Old Answer:**

The problem is `transition` property cannot be applied to the CSS property `display:none`, the workaround for this is to set the height to 0px initially, a problem you will face is that the text will still be visible on the screen. For this overflowing text to be hidden, use the CSS class `overflow:hidden` which will hide the content which is outside the element. Also instead of using transition on the parent element, use it directly on the element itself. Refer the below class.

```
.show{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    bottom:0;
    height:0px;
    width:100%;
    color:#000;
    text-indent:5px;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

The transition property should be as follows.

```
transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
```

First mention which property should have the transition effect. Then duration of the transition, then whether `ease-in` or some other setting.

Then on hover, set the original height. The transition will be seen.

```
.container:hover > .show{
    height:50%;
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #00f;
  position: relative;
}

.show {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  text-indent: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container:hover>.show {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="show">Lorem </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but I was thinking about different 'animation'. I am trying to get sth like that: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_overlay_opacity
but only with 30% height.
This effect should not be like 'slide in (bottom)', I am trying to get 'fade in a box' example.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_overlay.asp

Comment: @Misiek777 Updated my answer, please mention everything in your question. I have made the box appear at the bottom, if you want to make it appear from the top change the CSS property `bottom:0px` to `top:0px` in the class `show`